# Linear equation system in modular aritmetic

Tags: algorithms, modular-arithmetic

Can someone explain me how to solve linear equation system in modular aritmetic when i have less equations than variables. I need algorithm for this, something with gaussian matrix maybe.

$$4x_1 - 2x_2 + 0x_3 = 2$$
$$-x_3 + 4x_4=1$$
Where everything is in modulo = 3

Matrice for this system is 
$ \left( \begin{array}{ccc}
1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 2 \\
0 & 0 & 2 & 1 & 1 \\
\end{array} \right)$ i think.
I need only a "smallest"solution. In this case it is $(0,2,0,1)$.

I know that there are 9 solutions for this system.Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If you are working only over fields $\rm\:\Bbb Z/p,\:$ for prime $\rm\:p,\:$ then [Gaussian elimination](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_elimination) works fine (as it does over any field). For more general coefficient rings there are various generalizations, such as [Hermite](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hermite_normal_form) and [Smith](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smith_normal_form) normal form algorithms.

Comment: I still don't get how to get that "smallest"solution from that matrice :/

Comment: @JoshuaM You only now mentioned that you needed only a "smallest" solution.  My answer is to your original question - which gave no hint of that constraint.

Comment: Yea I know, and can you help me with the "smallest"solution ?:)

Comment: @JoshuaM For the minimization problem you might find some techniques of interest by searching on "frobenius problem linear programming".

Answer (score 0):

Everything's modulo $\,3\,$ :

$$4x_1-2x_2=2\iff x_1+x_2=2\iff x_2=2+2x_1$$

$$-x_3+x_4=1\iff 2x_3+x_4=1\iff x_4=1+x_3$$

So the general solution has the form

$$\left\{\,\begin{pmatrix}x_2\\2+2x_1\\x_3\\1+x_3\end{pmatrix}\;;\;\;x_1\,,\,x_3\in\Bbb F\right\}$$

Where $\,\Bbb F\,$ is the algebraic structure from where the variables are taken (seemingly,  field with characteristic $\,3\,$)

Comment: Can you explain me how to make algorithm for that? If I am given less equation than variables? I need only the smallest solution. In this case it is (0,2,0,1)

Comment: I'm not sure how "smallest" and "biggest" orwhatever work in field with positive characteristic...anyway, the above is just ismple linear algebra appleid to a field of char. $\,3\,$ ...